# Move, wibble, a UIView, attached to a spring, using the accelerometer

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics-engine

Say you have a simple square UIView sitting in the view of a view controller:

```
@IBOutlet var redSquare: UIView!
```

[image]

Imagine it can move up/down left/right slightly. TBC it simply stays in the same totally normal 3D plane, it remains an ordinary "square of red" on the glass screen; it does not even rotate.

[image]

In iOS (1) you can access the **motion manager** along the lines...

```
let mm: CMMotionManager = CMMotionManager()
mm.startAccelerometerUpdates()
```

and you can (2) make an object "be attached to a **spring**" along the lines...

```
sumthin.physicsBody.dynamic = true
sumthin.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
sumthin.physicsBody.mass = 1
```

finally (3) you can **apply force**, to an object, **based on the accelerometer** with something like...

```
f = mm.accelerometerData
sumthin.physicsBody.applyForce(
      CGVectorMake(CGFloat(f.acceleration.x), CGFloat(f.acceleration.y)))
```

GOAL: As you shake the phone around ...

[image]

the red square will simply "wibble" up/down, left-right a bit (perhaps 10 points or so, just to be clear); when you stop moving your hand it will settle as if on a spring back to the original position.

How do you do this, with an ordinary UIView?